# Show that $\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}+\sqrt[n]{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\dots(1-x_n)}\leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Question: Let $x_i\in(0,\frac12]$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Show that
$$\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}+\sqrt[n]{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\dots(1-x_n)}\leq 1$$
without using optmization techniques in calculus.

My try: For $n=1$, it is trivially true. For $n=2$, let $x_1=u^2,x_2=v^2$. Then,
$$\sqrt{1-u^2-v^2+u^2v^2}\leq 1-uv$$
then after squaring
$$0\leq (u-v)^2.$$
At $n=3$, I am stuck. Is there an easier method to prove this inequality? Also, what is the lower bound of this sum? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_inequality

Comment: What is the lower bound? There was a second part of question.

Comment: The upper bound is what you are asking for in the title, and what has been asked and answered before  (in fact more than once: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29357). I would suggest that you ask a separate question for the lower bound.

Comment: I *think* that Mahler's inequality also helps to determine the miminal value and I might have a solution for that. But again, it is better to ask that separately IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using AM-GM inequality, $$\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\dots x_n}+\sqrt[n]{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)\dots(1-x_n)}\leq \frac{x_1+\ldots+x_n}{n} + \frac{n-(x_1+\ldots+x_n)}{n} = 1$$

Answer (score 4):

Because by Holder:
$$1=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i+1-x_i)}\geq\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^nx_i}+\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x_i)}.$$